# error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setText:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

hi i am writing a temperature converter program in objective c for i phone my code is given below i am getting an error ""error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setText:"" please somebody help me to solve my problem

```
1. interface section

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface farh_celcius_conv_AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UILabel *display;
    IBOutlet UITextField *farhenite;
    IBOutlet UIButton *convert;
    float n ;
    float k;
}

-(IBAction) convert; 


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *display;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *farhenite;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *convert;
@end

2. implementation section
#import "farh_celcius_conv_AppDelegate.h"

@implementation farh_celcius_conv_AppDelegate

@synthesize window,display,farhenite;

-(IBAction) convert {

    NSString *str = [NSString txt];

    float n = [str floatValue];

    k = (n - 32)*(5/9);

        [display setText: k]; 

   // error:incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setText:

}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'k' is not a `NSString`. Try this

```
[display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",k]];
```

Comment: it still gives an error over that line error: expected ']' before 'OBJC_STRING' token

Comment: Sorry missed a : in between. Try now

Comment: @ 7kv7 it worked thanks . the simulator launches but when i put a value it does not gives an output it just hangs for a while and then disappears .

Answer (score 4):

can you try

```
 display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",k];
```

also change this line

```
NSString *str = youStr  //rather than [NSString txt].
```

Comment: @ iphone pgr   it still gives an error over that line error: expected ']' before 'OBJC_STRING' token

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Because, k is not a NSString.

```
-(IBAction) convert {

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", farhenite.text];

    float n = [str floatValue];

    k = (n - 32)*(5/9);

        //[display setText: k]; 
   display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", k];

   // error:incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setText:

}
```

Comment: @ chetan bhalara  it still gives an error over that line error: expected ']' before 'OBJC_STRING' token

Comment: @ chetan bhalara  it still gives an error  error: request for member 'txt' in something not a structure or union

Comment: Now try it again. I have change txt to text.

Comment: @ chetan bhalara thanks dear it worked. is rest of the program ok because the simulator launches the application but when i enter a value it does not perform anything just hangs for a second and then disappears . please help if u can

Comment: Yes I can do it. Can u come on skype?

Comment: @ chetan bhalara sry dear i m new in this company and dont having skype installed on my pc . but thanks dear for ur kind help

Comment: Its Ok, Just give me some more detail of your problem, I will try to solve it.

Comment: @ chetan bhalara in the iphone simulator when i put the value in farheniet textfield and press the convert button it keeps on pressed and is not released and then the simulator disappears

Comment: @ cheatn bhalara and it also gives a msg "terminating due to uncaught exception"

Comment: @ chetan bhalara it does not give error on some line but it gives this error on the bar from  where we start writing our program and error comes when the simulator disappears.

Comment: Run your application in debug mode and then you can see where this msg come.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",k]];
```